# Al seleccionar un tercer item de un DropDownList no redirecciona a la página

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tengo una página Login con un DropDownList con: 1.Usuarios 2. Administrador 3. Liquidacion
 Redireccionan según lo seleccionado presionando un botón:
Evento OnClick:

```
using (cmd = new OdbcCommand("", cn))
        {
            OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                if (this.List.SelectedItem.Value == "Administrador")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Administrador.aspx");
                }
                else if (this.List.SelectedItem.Value == "Usuario")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Usuarios.aspx?id=" + Usser.SelectedItem.Value);
                }
                else if (this.List.SelectedItem.Value == "Liquidacion")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Liquidacion.aspx");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Abc.Text = ("Datos incorrectos");
            }
        }
```

PROBLEMA:
Me reconoce cuando ingreso por Administrador o usuario, pero no por liquidación

Comment: ¿Has comprobado si entra en ese if? De primeras se me ocurre que haya un error al escribir la palabra. Al llevar tilde a lo mejor has errado al escribirla, que se le esté pasando el valor "liquidación" con acento y tratando como "liquidacion" sin acento

Comment: De hecho eh revisado eso, no tiene la tilde, si pruebo con otro botón me agarra, y no es problema con el DropDownList pues me reconoce los datos ya que no marca error, el problema es el if, pero eh copiado y pegado la palabra desde el drop y aún así no me permite re dirigir, la pagina simplemente se actualiza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar un switch (para no validar el mismo datos varias veces) de la siguiente forma:

```
    switch(List.SelectedItem.Value.ToString().ToUpper)/*el this. es redundante y puede ser que el ToString() tambien pero por las dudas*/
    {
        case "ADMINISTRADOR" /*importante en mayuscula*/:
             //codigo
             break;
        case "USUARIO" /*importante en mayuscula*/:
             //codigo
             break;
    }
```

Espero te sirva!